# encrypt decrypt voice

Tags: phone-call

I want to develop a program like below image.
When you are in a voice call, if you start myApplication, then your voice first go to my program and encrypt with my code then send it over voice,
and other side voice decrypt in my application and play in speaker.

[image]

my friend said I can not do this and I should use voip or data channel.

Answer (score 0):

you can't because voice transmission has lots of noise and it's only because of human hearing error that we can't understand there is even a noise in the first place. voip or data channel securely transmite data so you can easily decode what you encoded, but only using voice will generate too much noise that the received data is almost unusable.